# How to convert an String array to a float array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

How to convert an `String` array to a `float` array?
For example:

```
String[] arr = new String[] {"1.1","2.2","3.3","4.4","5.5"};
```

At the end it should be a float array.

Comment: @jhamon does this work also for arrays

Comment: It works for array *elements*. You will need to create resulting array yourself and *fill* it with results of method mentioned in duplicate.

Comment: 1. Create a `float[]` with the same length as `arr`. 2. Iterate `arr`. 3. Use [`Float.parseFloat(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)) on every string. 4. Add the result to the float array.